# IE and unspecified error while using qzprint (jzebra)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html2canvas

Hi I am trying to print an HTML page.
It prints in all other browsers except IE.
In IE, it gives me an **"Unspecified error"** in html2canvas.js
The version of html2canvas.js is 0.34.
I have tried using the latest version viz 0.4.1 but it fails at some other point.
The sample.html provided with the applet works fine and most of my code is borrowed from that.

The error occurs at the last line of the following code in html2canvas.js

```
_html2canvas.Util.Bounds = function getBounds (el) {
    var clientRect,
    bounds = {};

    if (el.getBoundingClientRect){
        clientRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Any clues and hints are really appreciated.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    useDefaultPrinter(function () {

        if (!isLoaded()) {
            alert("Printer is not loaded, please try again.");
            return;
        }

        window['qzDonePrinting'] = function () {
            // After print functionality
            if ($('input[name=action]').length > 0)
                document.getElementById('frm_next').submit();
            else {
                var query_param = 'coid=8EY76KFTYGWF6';
                send_ajax_request(query_param, function () {
                    var href = '/path/to/homepage';
                    if (JSON_data.SUCCESS == 1)
                        href += '?coid=' + JSON_data.RET_COID;
                    window.location.href = href;
                });
            }

            // Remove reference to this function
            window['qzDonePrinting'] = null;
        };
        printHTML5Page();
    });
});

function printHTML5Page() {
   $("body").html2canvas({
      canvas: hidden_screenshot,
      onrendered: function() {
         if (notReady()) { return; }
         // Optional, set up custom page size.  These only work for PostScript printing.
         // setPaperSize() must be called before setAutoSize(), setOrientation(), etc.
         qz.setPaperSize("8.5in", "11.0in");  // US Letter
         qz.setAutoSize(true);
         qz.appendImage($("canvas")[0].toDataURL('image/png'));
         // Automatically gets called when "qz.appendFile()" is finished.
         window['qzDoneAppending'] = function() {
            // Tell the applet to print.
            qz.printPS();

            // Remove reference to this function
            window['qzDoneAppending'] = null;
         };
      }
   });
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas relies on the HTML5 specification which is not supported by older verisons of Internet Explorer.  Depending on your IE version, this functionality may not be supported with your browser.